# What should I do to edit or rename CKEDITOR toolbar buttons (hover text) ? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR, and I have to change the names of the buttons that we get in the toolbar i.e. the text that we see when we hover over the buttons. I was wondering if that is a possible requirement? if yes can anyone help me or point me in a direction where I can find an answer to my query?

Comment: You have the source code, it's open source so it's definitely possible. Check button hover text and search the source code for the same string.

Comment: Just edit the relevant language file, which you'll find in the "lang" directory.

Comment: I have not downloaded / Installed the ckeditor locally. I am just using the javascript file they have on - "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/full/ckeditor.js".  So is there a way I can do that without having to edit or change their source code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Definitely it is possible .Please go to respective respective plugin directory, then lang directory there we find language setting files like en.js Inside that file you will rename button.
for example: 
If we want to rename table properties button name. Go to CKEditor/plugin/table/lang then inside this we find en.js from that file you will get button settings.